# Angular and Bootstrap Templates

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular4-forms

I am a javascript developer and want to create a responsive webapp. I am confused between the options like should i design of mine or use templates like https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/forms/general.html
http://akveo.com/ngx-admin/pages/modal-overlays/popover

What are the pros and cons of using such templates. Please help.

Comment: What did you end up doing ?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah using the angular is good choice. Using the templates are great way to bootstrap the any project but my suggestion is keep the template as a reference ..create your own component and just take the part from the templates that you need because using the entire template will increase your production build size and affects the overall performance as well

Answer (score 0):

Using an angular template sounds great and all but you're more than likely not going to use *all* of the features they implemented resulting in huge bloat.

I would use a template as a frame of reference and implement the component(s) yourself. I've seen a "template" like FUSE add over 27MB of code in a distribution build.

Also you're dealing with an abstraction of which you'll have to learn *how* they do things to get your things working.